# compiled executables not working on the server

Tags: monerod

I compiled binary files (monerod and monero-wallet-rpc) and tried to run them on another machine on a Docker container and got this error:

`./start.sh: line 3:     6 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) ./monerod --restricted-rpc --confirm-external-bind --non-interactive --config-file /root/monero/data/monero.conf --detach
./start.sh: line 3:     6 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) ./monerod --restricted-rpc --confirm-external-bind --non-interactive --config-file /root/monero/data/monero.conf --detach
./start.sh: line 3:     5 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) ./monerod --restricted-rpc --confirm-external-bind --non-interactive --config-file /root/monero/data/monero.conf --detach
./start.sh: line 3:     5 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) ./monerod --restricted-rpc --confirm-external-bind --non-interactive --config-file /root/monero/data/monero.conf --detach
./start.sh: line 3:     6 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) ./monerod --restricted-rpc --confirm-external-bind --non-interactive --config-file /root/monero/data/monero.conf --detach
./start.sh: line 3:     6 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) ./monerod --restricted-rpc --confirm-external-bind --non-interactive --config-file /root/monero/data/monero.conf --detach
./start.sh: line 3:     6 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) ./monerod --restricted-rpc --confirm-external-bind --non-interactive --config-file /root/monero/data/monero.conf --detach`

Has someone had this issue before?

Answer (score 2):

The `Illegal instruction` error usually happens when trying to run a program that was compiled for another CPU architecture.

I guess the architecture of the computer on which you compiled the binary and the architecture of the computer on which you are trying run it are different.
If that's the case, instead of a regular compilation, you will have to either cross-compile for the second machine's architecture or compile directly on the second machine.